# iPhone Development - NSDate - help with my clock

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsdate

How can i make a label that acts as a clock.

I guess that the steps are:
1- initializing the label with current time in ViewDidLoad
2- NSTimer and updating the label each second.

I can do the timer thing but i need a help in getting the instant time.
I think it is related to [NSDate ...] and [NSDateFormatter ..].

thanks in advance.